# Value overwriten after postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a reporting.aspx page. If the page loads without parameters it shows a list of projects, clicking one of the projects will load the same page with a projectId-parameter and shows the actual report of that project.

This report has two textboxes: FromDateText and ToDateText. The text of those two boxes should either be todays date or it should be the value of two more parameters of the URL. My problem is, that it will re-initialize the text of the two boxes with today's date before the button can call the Response.Redirect.

A bit of code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool projectIdAvailable = this.Request.QueryString["ProjectID"] != null;
        if (!projectIdAvailable)
        {
            // Load list with buttons
            // Each button loads the page again with a ProjectId as parameter
            foreach (var project in ListOfAllProjects)
            {
                var button = new Button
                    {
                        Text = project.Name,
                        PostBackUrl = string.Format("Reporting.aspx?ProjectID={0}", project.Id)
                    };
                MyPanel.Controls.Add(button);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Can't use if (!IsPostBack) as it will always be a postback at this place.
            LoadReporting();
        }
    }

    private void LoadReporting()
    {
        // If we have date as parameter use it, else take today
        if (this.Request.QueryString["fromDate"] != null)
        {
            this.FromDateText.Text = this.Request.QueryString["fromDate"];
        }
        else
        {
            this.FromDateText.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        }

        if (this.Request.QueryString["toDate"] != null)
        {
            this.ToDateText.Text = this.Request.QueryString["toDate"];
        }
        else
        {
            this.ToDateText.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        }

        // Reporting generates a table here...
    }

    // Refresh the page with date parameters
    protected void RefreshButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int projectId = int.Parse(this.Request.QueryString["ProjectID"]);
        this.Response.Redirect(
            string.Format(
                "Reporting.aspx?ProjectID={0}&fromDate={1}&toDate={2}",
                projectId,
                this.FromDateText.Text,
                this.ToDateText.Text));
    }
```

The best solution I could come up with is to not write the current date in the textbox, this way it won't overwrite itself or I could use a bit of JavaScript so I won't get a postback.

Neither seem like a very good way. What would be the good way to do it?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @NicholasV.: As the page reloads itself with a parameter and only then loads the reporting, the LoadReporting() part would never load if I would only call it inside a if(!IsPostBack).

Answer (score 2):

You should load data only `if(!IsPostBack`) and not on every postback.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool projectIdAvailable = this.Request.QueryString["ProjectID"] != null;
    if (!projectIdAvailable)
    {
        // Load list with buttons
        // PostBackUrl = "Reporting.aspx?ProjectID=0"
    }
    else
    {
        if(!IsPostBack)
            LoadReporting();
    }
}
```

The content is persisted in `ViewState` by default, so no need to load it again everytime.

Comment: But it will always be a postback if I load the reporting, as you have to click one of the generated buttons in the if(!projectIdAvailable) part to get to the LoadReporting().

Comment: Why don't you use normal ASP.NET buttons to postback and why do you use `Response.Redirect` to load the same page?

Comment: I generate the buttons during runtime because the number of projects is variable (I will add a bit more code). What else should I use than Response.Redirect? I just wanted one page that reacts differently depending on the parameters. Should I just use two pages?

Comment: I have not yet the time to dig deeper. But why don't you use a web databound control like `Repeater` to create the controls dynamically? I would even wrap them in a UserControl which reduces complexity and increases reusability and maintainability. You don't need to reload the page, you just have to assign the DataSource to the control(like `Repeater`) and then call `DataBind()`.

Comment: I usually don't work with ASP.NET, so the simple reason is: I didn't know what the best way is, so I just did everything manually. But how would a repeater change anything? edit: Thank you, I will take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Try loading inside `!ispostback`..Otherwise the value get reset on every postbacks..

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool projectIdAvailable = this.Request.QueryString["ProjectID"] != null;
    if (!projectIdAvailable)
    {
        // Load list with buttons
        // PostBackUrl = "Reporting.aspx?ProjectID=0"
    }
    else
    {
        if(!IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadReporting();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But it will always be a postback if I load the reporting, as you have to click one of the generated buttons in the if(!projectIdAvailable) part to get to the LoadReporting().